# Naming PK and FK

Tags: database, authentication, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have login form for my student app, since that I create tbl_user (for login) , tbl_teacher (for biodata) and tbl_student (for biodata). tbl_user have columns (username (PK), password, role, status). tbl_teacher have columns (bio_teacher_id (PK), teacher_id (FK), name, address, etc). tbl_student have columns (bio_student_id (PK), student_number (FK), name, address, etc). Explanation :
To login, teacher use "teacher_id" as username, student use "student_number" as username.
My question : Can anyone suggest me ebook/ journal/ supporting document that explain we can use different naming for FK from the PK of parent table ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

All database systems that I know of allow an FK too have a different name from the PK that they point to. I'm not aware of any statement that says so because very, very few people ever imagined that this is not the case.

A simple test is for you try to create an FK relation where the columns have different names and see whether it words or not. As I say, I don't know of any DBMS where it won't - if you find one I'd be interested in knowing!